# why findchessboardcorners provides me in float values?

Tags: opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am tring to figure out the chess board corners using openCV API. Below is the code snippet.

```
leftImage = cv2.imread ("left.jpg")
retVal, detectedCorners = cv2.findChessboardCorners (leftImage, (7, 6))
```

Now, detectedCorners[0] gives below values.

```
array([[ 475.44540405,  264.75949097]], dtype=float32)
```

**My Question is :**

How these pixels coordinate values are represented in the float value. It must have been the integer value of (x,y) in image?

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t delved into the code yet. But I bet OpenCV is is using Harris corners here and calculating the sub pixel locations as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html)

Answer (score 1):

The result type is correct. They may decided it `float` to get more accurate results. As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#the-calibration-and-save) says:

> The image points: This is a vector of **Point2f** vector which for
>   each input image contains coordinates of the important points (corners
>   for chessboard and centers of the circles for the circle pattern).
>   **We have already collected this from findChessboardCorners or findCirclesGrid function. We just need to pass it on.**

Comment: correct, but i am curious to think how a pixel shall be represented in float values. :)